# Remove style from an actionlink

Tags: c#, css, actionlink

I have an actionlink as such,

```
    <td>

        @Ajax.ActionLink(
            item.FirstName,
            "DisplayApplication",
            new { ID = item.ColleagueID },
            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Application" }
        )

    </td>
```

I want this to appear just as normal text does on the rest of my website without the normal styling that a link will have, but there doesn't seem to be a command that restores to default or anything like that that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try another overload of `Ajax.ActionLink` to pass style attribute:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
            item.FirstName,
            "DisplayApplication",
            new { ID = item.ColleagueID },
            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Application" },
            new { @style="text-decoration: none;color:black" }
        );
```

Comment: you should separate styling from logic. You can just as easy use a CSS class

Comment: I agree, a class attribute should be better